# Shape recognition, hough transform

Tags: opencv, hough-transform, shape-analysis

I'm trying to match a picture saying "this is ducks, this is towers" by giving votes  from the hough transform of a picture.

I've found this article http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~smaji/papers/hough-cvpr09.pdf, but I didn't find a implemented code (and I'm trying several things).

Do you know anything similar to that, for example included on OpenCV?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hough forests for object recognition are initially proposed by Jurgen Gal. The paper was named "Class Specific Hough Forests for Object Recognition".

[Here](http://files.is.tue.mpg.de/jgall/projects/houghforest/houghforest.html) is his homepage. [Here](http://files.is.tue.mpg.de/jgall/projects/houghforest/houghforest.html) are the source code and the details. I think you could make use of those.

Certainly better methods exist and one could well talk about them. However I am sticking to the Hough framework, as you mentioned that in the first place.

Comment: Thank you.
I'm not interesting in detecting objets, but seeing how close it is. On the webpage there's a code called "Scalable Multiclass Object Detection" but the code is broken. That's what I'm looking for, calculating the image number and compare it with the previous numbers that I've calculated before... do you know anything about that code?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it is broken. It is better if you contact the author for further details.

Comment: http://files.is.tue.mpg.de/jgall/projects/houghMC/houghMC.html

For contacting, it's broken as well :\

Comment: You can contact Juergen here:
http://files.is.tue.mpg.de/jgall/